# como mudar uma src de imagem de uma outra página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Olá, tenho um input onde serve como uma barra de pesquisa. Ao digitar um nome e apertar enter, uma função é ativada e executa a seguinte função:

```
function verificaValor(){
   var valor = $('#search').val();
   switch (valor) {   
      case "scripts":
        window.location.href = 'scripts.html';
        document.getElementById("imgDinamica").src="Slide1.png";
      break;
```

Ao digitar scripts ele vai para outra página, porém não muda a imagem. Como faço para mudar a imagem de uma outra página?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dá pra fazer usando só JavaScript se é o que você quer. Eu faria assim:

No lugar daquela sua linha:

```
window.location.href = 'scripts.html?imagem=Slide1';
```

E na página `scripts.html`, em algum lugar **depois** de onde essa `imgDinamica` aparece:

```
/// copiado de http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var imagem = getParameterByName('imagem');
if (imagem !== null) {
    document.getElementById("imgDinamica").src = imagem + ".png";
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! muitíssimo obrigado! você não faz ideia de como me ajudou. ^^

Comment: De nada, @GuilhermeS.Santos! Eu fico muito contente em ajudar, e mais ainda quando voltam pra agradecer e dizer que foi útil.